# Getting error Error:Execution failed for task 'Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > j

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > java.util.NoSuchElementException (no error message)
Here is app build gradle file

```
   android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        repositories {
        mavenCentral()
       }
    defaultConfig {
        ......           
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }            
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
}
```

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Ok Solved i changes dependency '2.0.0-alpha6' to '1.5.0' in build.gradle